# Nuxt won't load page without browser refresh

Tags: nuxt.js, netlify

Running into an issue with my Nuxt app where it won't render pages visited from link without manually refreshing browser after being hosted on Netlify. Had no issues in local development, but after clicking a link the 404 page loads and "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" comes into the console. This is my first experience working with Nuxt and i've been banging my head trying to figure out what is keeping the page from loading.

nuxt.config.js:

```
require("dotenv").config();
import colors from "vuetify/es5/util/colors";
const path = require("path");
import axios from "axios";
const collect = require("collect.js");

export default {
  mode: "universal",
  /*
   ** Headers of the page
   */
  head: {
    titleTemplate: "%s - " + process.env.npm_package_name,
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || "",
    meta: [
      { charset: "utf-8" },
      { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" },
      {
        hid: "description",
        name: "description",
        content: process.env.npm_package_description || ""
      }
    ],
    link: [{ rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.ico" }]
  },
  /*
   ** Customize the progress-bar color
   */
  loading: { color: "#92C83E" },
  /*
   ** Global CSS
   */
  css: [],
  /*
   ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
   */
  plugins: ["~/plugins/filters.js"],
  /*
   ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
   */
  buildModules: ["@nuxtjs/vuetify"],
  /*
   ** Nuxt.js modules
   */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    "@nuxtjs/axios",
    ["@nuxtjs/dotenv", { systemvars: true }]
  ],
  /*
   ** Axios module configuration
   ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
   */
  axios: {},
  /*
   ** vuetify module configuration
   ** https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module
   */

  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ["~/assets/variables.scss"],
    theme: {
      dark: true,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        }
      }
    }
  },
  generate: {
    routes: async () => {
      let { data } = await axios.post(
        process.env.POSTS_URL,
        JSON.stringify({
          filter: { published: true },
          sort: { _created: -1 },
          populate: 1
        }),
        {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        }
      );

      const collection = collect(data.entries);

      let tags = collection
        .map(post => post.tags)
        .flatten()
        .unique()
        .map(tag => {
          let payload = collection
            .filter(item => {
              return collect(item.tags).contains(tag);
            })
            .all();

          return {
            route: `category/${tag}`,
            payload: payload
          };
        })
        .all();

      let posts = collection
        .map(post => {
          return {
            route: `blog/${post.title_slug}`,
            payload: post
          };
        })
        .all();

      return posts.concat(tags);
    }
  },
  /*
   ** Build configuration
   */
  build: {
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    extend(config, ctx) {}
  }
};
```

_redirects:

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

Github repo: https://github.com/huntertrammell/techaccess
Netlify deploy: https://techaccess.netlify.com/

Comment: have you tried fixing the error shown in console first? `[Vuetify] Image load failed

src: http://localhost:8080/storage/uploads/2020/01/16/5e208b1d27140techaccessgreen.png

found in

---> <VImg>
       <RouterLink>
         <VCard>
           <VAppBar>
             <VApp>
               <Anonymous>
                 <Root>` seems you end up in a error page/layout the first time

Comment: I fixed it, but don't believe it was related. Appears to be along the lines of a CORS issue, but both the api & netlify are secured over ssl so not sure why. Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/' from origin 'https://techaccess.netlify.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. is the error its giving. already enabled cors for the api in Azure portal. never had this issue with netlify before so a bit confusing